# How to make a petty url in yii framework pagination

Tags: url, yii, pagination

How can i make a petty url format in yii framework clistview and cgridview pagination like: mysite.com/blog/page/2

Current Url is 
mysite.com/blog.html?Blog_page=2

I want
mysite.com/blog/page/2.html

Comment: try to put in your url rules  'blog/page/<Blog_page:\d+>'=>'blog/index',

Comment: this is a Problem of the Url Manager. Take a look at this: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url